# C# MongoDB update field via property

Tags: c#, mongodb, properties

There is a question, suppose we have such type:

```
public class Foo 
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }    

    [BsonElement]
    protected string _bar;
    public string BarProperty { get => _bar; set => _bar = value; }
}
```

I want to update `_bar` field via `BarProperty` using mongo update:

```
public void SetBar(string id, string bar)
{
    var f = Builders<Foo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
    var u = Builders<Foo>.Update.Set(x => x.BarProperty, bar);

    // `Collection` is IMongoCollection<Foo>
    Collection.UpdateOne(f, u);
}
```

We have some problems after update:

1. `_bar` has not changed;
2. `BarProperty` appeared in object in database;
   (if I use `[BsonIgnore]` it leads to error - `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.BarProperty.`

Is there any way when we have `_bar` updated (in db and in instance) and `BarProperty` is not serialized?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is bypassing the actual field name you want to update.

```cs
public void SetBar(string id, string bar)
{
    var f = Builders<Foo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
    var u = Builders<Foo>.Update.Set("_bar", bar);

    Collection.UpdateOne(f, u);
}
```

Is there a reason why you can't have the bar property public?

Comment: Task is a little bit more complex, I have base class:
`public class Base { protected BsonDocument Data { get; set; } }`
and inheritor:
`public class Child : Base { public string Bar { get => Data.Get<string>("Bar"); set => Data["Bar"] = value; } }`

I want to use property as access to `Data` field and store only `Data` in database